# XSLT - converting list into nested elements

Tags: xslt

How do we convert repeated related items at the same hierarchy level into nicely nested elements?

I have XML something like this as output from a complex SQL query from a forms-engine, collecting information, like a CV, where some fields (like previous jobs) can be repeated.  They aren't output in a friendly way, however:

```
<People>
  <Person>
    <Field1>Fred</Field1>
    <Field2>Head Chef</Field2>
    <Field3>The Ritz Hotel</Field3>
    <Field2>Bottle Washer</Field2>
    <Field3>Dog and Duck</Field3>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Field1>Mary</Field1>
    <Field2>Chief Executive</Field2>
    <Field3>BigCorp</Field3>
    <Field2>Manager</Field2>
    <Field3>LargeCorp</Field3>
    <Field2>Mail Clerk</Field2>
    <Field3>SmallCorp</Field3>
  </Person>
</People>
```

What I need to do is transform this into other XML, to separate out the repeated sets of Field2 and Field3 into separate parent elements, something like this...

```
<People>
  <Person>
    <Name>Fred</Name>
    <Jobs>
      <Job>
        <JobTitle>Head Chef</JobTitle>
        <Employer>Ritz Hotel</Employer>
      </Job>
      <Job>
        <JobTitle>Bottle Washer</JobTitle>
        <Employer>Dog and Duck</Employer>
      </Job>
    </Jobs>
  </Person>

  <Person>
    <Name>Mary</Name>
    <Jobs>
      <Job>
        <JobTitle>Chief Executive</JobTitle>
        <Employer>BigCorp</Employer>
      </Job>
      <Job>
        <JobTitle>Manager</JobTitle>
        <Employer>LargeCorp</Employer>
      </Job>
      <Job>
        <JobTitle>Mail Clerk</JobTitle>
        <Employer>SmallCorp</Employer>
      </Job>
    </Jobs>
  </Person>
</People>
```

The fields will always be in order - i.e. Field1 then Field2, then optionally another Field1 and Field2, optionally repeated ad nauseum.
I have code that does the simple stuff for the single-occurrence fields (of which there are many, of course), but there are potentially several repeating sets of fields like this (education history, employment history, etc.) that I need to sort out.  Don't worry about where to get the names for the translations (e.g. from "Field3" to "Employer") as I can sort that out, I think. 
If it helps with parsing I can adjust the names of the input elements - e.g. to append a sequence ordinal number to group the related elements, something like:

```
...
    <Field2_Seq1>Head Chef</Field2_Seq1>
    <Field3_Seq1>The Ritz Hotel</Field3_Seq1>
    <Field2_Seq2>Bottle Washer</Field2_Seq2>
    <Field3_Seq2>Dog and Duck</Field3_Seq2>
....
```

I'm struggling heavily with this - I'm new to XSL and under pressure to get it working (when are we not?), so any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Keith.

Edit: In reality there are more fields in the repeating sets (e.g. Field4, Field5... FieldN) and they are optional, so we may have omitted items in the sequence: those that are present will be in ascending but not necessarily sequential order.  The trigger for a new Job element is that the numbers have gone backwards (e.g. from Field6 to Field3).
So we need to cope with, e.g.

```
...
<Field1>John</Field1>
<Field4>Something</Field4>
<Field6>Missed some more</Field6>
<Field2>New Job</Field2>
...
```

Yielding something like (partial)

```
...
<Person>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Job>
    <SomeElement>Something</SomeElement>
    <YetAnother>Missed some more</YetAnother>
  </Job>
  <Job>
    <JobTitle>New Job</JobTitle>
...
```

Apologies for inadequate original question example.

Comment: So how do you want `Field4`, `Field5` and `Field5` processed? What should be generated for each of them?

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Can you select an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet should do the trick ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <People>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="People/Person"/>
 </People>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
 <xsl:copy>
  <Name><xsl:value-of select="Field1"/></Name>
  <jobs>
   <xsl:for-each select="*[not( substring( local-name( preceding-sibling::*
                     [substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1][1]),6) &lt;
                    substring( local-name(), 6))
                    and substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1]">
    <job>
      <xsl:variable name="id-of-head" select="generate-id()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
       .|(following-sibling::*[
         $id-of-head = generate-id(
      preceding-sibling::*[not( substring( local-name( preceding-sibling::*
                     [substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1][1]),6) &lt;
                    substring( local-name(), 6))][1])]
      [substring( local-name( preceding-sibling::*
                     [substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1][1]),6) &lt;
                    substring( local-name(), 6)])" />
    </job>  
   </xsl:for-each> 
  </jobs>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field2" priority="1">
  <JobTitle><xsl:value-of select="." /></JobTitle> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field3" priority="1">
  <Employer><xsl:value-of select="." /></Employer> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:comment>You haven't defined a translation for this field yet.
To do so, just add another template.
See templates for Fields 2 and 3 for example.</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There should be smart way to do the equivalent with keys. Let us know if you can use XSLT 2.0, because that will make the solution **A lot smaller and simpler**.

## UPDATE

I converted this style-sheet into a key-using form, which might be a bit more read-able. I am not sure if it qualifies as muenchian or quasi-muenchian? Here is is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="job"
  match="
  Person/*
    [starts-with(local-name(),'Field')]
    [substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1]"
  use="
  generate-id( (.|preceding-sibling::*)
    [starts-with(local-name(),'Field')]
    [substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1]
    [
     (position() = 1)
      or
     ( substring( local-name(), 6)
        &lt;
     substring(
       local-name( preceding-sibling::*
       [starts-with(local-name(),'Field')]
       [1]
           ), 6
          )
     )
    ]
    [last()])"
  />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <People>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="People/Person"/>
 </People>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
 <xsl:copy>
  <Name><xsl:value-of select="Field1"/></Name>
  <jobs>
   <xsl:for-each select="
    *
    [starts-with(local-name(),'Field')]
    [substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1]
    [
     (position() = 1)
        or
     ( substring( local-name(), 6)
        &lt;
       substring(
       local-name( preceding-sibling::*
         [starts-with(local-name(),'Field')]
         [1]
             ), 6
          )
      )
     ]">
    <job>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('job',generate-id(.))" />
  </job>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </jobs>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field2" priority="1">
  <JobTitle><xsl:value-of select="." /></JobTitle>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field3" priority="1">
  <Employer><xsl:value-of select="." /></Employer>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[substring( local-name(), 6) &gt; 1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:comment>You haven't defined a translation for this field yet.
To do so, just add another template.
See templates for Fields 2 and 3 for example.</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wow, that looks fantastic - apologies for delay in response, I was out of the office and offline yesterday.  I'll try this and let you know.  There's certainly a lot more to XSLT than I thought (how naive of me).

Thank you so much for the effort put into this, it is greatly appreciated.  I'll comment back later.

Comment: That works brilliantly - I now need to work through and understand it, so I learn from this.  Thanks very much for the help Sean and also thanks to actionshrimp!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order, you can match on the first in the sequence, and then use following-sibling to get the subsequent elements (checking for the name of the following elements if you're not sure whether they will be there or not).

The below XSLT will convert your first XML to your first output XML. Try changing the following-sibling::*[1] to [2] etc to get further siblings:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Person">
        <Person>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="Field1"/></Name>
            <Jobs>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Field2"/>
            </Jobs>
        </Person>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Field2">
        <Job>
            <JobTitle><xsl:value-of select="."/></JobTitle>
            <xsl:if test="./following-sibling::*[1][name() = 'Field3']">
                <Employer><xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::*[1]"/></Employer>
            </xsl:if>
        </Job>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks to do the trick.  I'll experiment for a bit with the real thing to make sure I understand how to make it work fully. I can control the order (with the SQL), so the sequence will always be in sequence, though the field numbers may be sparse (i.e. not all are mandatory form fields).
I'll play around before marking as 'correct answer', but that looks really good so far - many thanks.

Comment: admitting my ignorance, I'm failing to extend this to the real situation.  So, with apologies for original example being too simplified, if I have more than 2 fields is there a more general solution.
As they are optional, is there a solution that allows any of Field2 through FieldN to be omitted?
Trigger for a new 'Job' element is that the Field number is less than the prev.  i.e. if we have Field1, Field 4, Field 6, Field5, we'd get a Job with Fields 4 and 6 and then another Job started at Field5 (since 5 is less than 6)?

Sorry for messing you around and thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the condition definitely along the lines of '5 is less than 6' or will 4 always map to one tag, 5 to another, 6 to another etc. and you just dont know whether the tags will be present or not?

Comment: The field numbers relate to the forms editor's internal IDs for the questions and I can ensure that they will be in ascending order within a group, or that each group has a distinct suffix/prefix, e.g. FieldN_GroupX. The XSLT needs have hard-coded names, so would output Field1 as Name and Field2 as JobTitle, etc. so each FieldN tag will need an explicit corresponding treatment in the XSLT to output as the appropriate real-world name.
In reality some fields are mandatory but some aren't, hence general case of all optional.  Not sure whether I've understood and answered your question.